# Adding labels to the middle of a sunburst on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I've been working on a sunburst visualization example provided by the following link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423. I want the label to display the name of the partition in question that has been moused over. Right now whenever I mouseover a partition it shows "flare" in the middle only. Is there a way for me to access the names of the children?

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
.data(partition.nodes) //access the nodes
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : 'none';}) //hide inner ring 
.attr("d", arc)//used whenever I come across a path 
.style("stroke", "#fff")
.style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);})
.style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
.each(stash)
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout);

var label = svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "tooltip")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 50)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function mouseover(d) {

  d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0.3);

label.style("opacity", .9); 


console.log('mouseover', mouseover);    
  };

function mouseout(d) {
d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 1);

        label.style("opacity", 0);

console.log('mouseout', mouseout);  
  };
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How do I add a label in the middle of a sunburst which works when i mouse over a partition?

Comment: Your code already has a mouseover handler function. Does this not work as intended, and if so, how?

Comment: The code isn't working because the event handler is not displaying the information I in the way I have described in the question. You can find the full code in the link to the below https://jsfiddle.net/odanga/kr2v7r08/

Comment: You'd only need to change `.text(function(d) { return d.name; })` for that, no?

Comment: I tried to make that change but it isn't working.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: The complete example was given in the fiddle link below https://jsfiddle.net/odanga/kr2v7r08/ all the code that is necessary has been put there. My problem is that when the mouseover is done the label is not appearing at all.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hey Lars, made changes to the question, I got the labels to appear in the middle. I've used  .text(function(d) { return d.name; }) to access the names of the children but all its giving me is "flare" as a result. Is there another way for me to access the names of the children?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307)? I think it's very close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes I have but its still using the previous method I used to access the labels, and I've even copied the text part of the code but that's not working either. I've put all my working code on this gist. In case you need to see it. https://gist.github.com/Odanga/bf7ca45906c3668ceccd

Comment: It looks like you're appending `text` to `path` elements -- this doesn't work in SVG. You need to add the `text` elements to either a `g` or the top-level SVG.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it has worked but now all the labels are appearing in the center causing them to overlap each other. I know the problem area is around the mouseover( ) function but I'm not sure how to fix it. How do I get it to show just one label in the center?

Comment: You're appending new `text` elements regardless of what's there. I would add a single `text` element with a specific ID outside of the mouse handler and update its text on mouseover.

Comment: Inside the handler, do something like `d3.select("#id").text(d.name);`

Comment: OMG!! it freaking worked! thank you so much for your patience! I've learnt a lot from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by first of all appending text elements to a g element and not svg element. Second you want to create a text element outside the mousehandler with a specific id then call it using that Id within the event handler like so.

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(partition.nodes(root))
.enter().append("g");

var path = 
        g.append("path")
        .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : 'none';}) //hide inner ring 
        .attr("d", arc)//used whenever I come across a path 
        .attr("id", "part")
        .style("stroke", "#fff")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);})
        .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
        .each(stash)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout);

var text = g.selectAll("text")
            .data(partition.nodes(root))
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("id", "tip")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 50)
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .style("opacity", 0);


function mouseover(d) {

  d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease('elastic')
        .style("opacity", 0.3);

//label.style("opacity", .9);
d3.select("#tip").text(d.name).style("opacity", 0.9);

console.log('mouseover', mouseover);    
};

function mouseout(d) {
d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 1);

d3.select("#tip").text(d.name).style("opacity", 0);

console.log('mouseout', mouseout);  
  };
```